# How to Create Categorical Column in Python based on Existing Column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm new to python
is there any simple way to create categorical values based on existing values in python?

```
city lapse
a    0
b    1
a    1
a    0
b    0
b    1
```

the column that I want to create is categorical of city based on the average lapse column

```
city avg_lapse city_class
a    0.3       < .5
b    0.6       > .5
```

and create a new column based on that calculation

```
city lapse city_class
a    0     < .5
b    1     > .5
a    1     < .5
a    0     < .5
b    0     > .5
b    1     > .5
```

currently, I'm exporting the clean data to csv, calculate the categories in excel, then upload it to python environment, any idea how to create an automated version of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat aggregate values, so possible create new column by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mean = df.groupby('city')['lapse'].transform('mean')
df['city_class'] = np.where(mean > 0.5, '> .5', '<= .5')
print (df)
  city  lapse  city_class
0    a      0       <= .5
1    b      1       >  .5
2    a      1       <= .5
3    a      0       <= .5
4    b      0       >  .5
5    b      1       >  .5
```